# get_month_link uses what wordpress template?

Tags: templates, api, template-hierarchy, codex

I tried using

`archive.php`
and
`category.php`

but always `index.php` is used of my template. How can I customize what template file is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`get_month_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_month_link) doesn't use any template. It just creates a link to date based archives. The actual template used is decided by a rather complicated [template hierarchy system managed](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) by Core. Essentially there is a cascading sequence of files that will be used if those files are provided by the theme:

1. `date.php`
2. `archive.php`
3. `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

I think I did a mistake with my IDE. It turns out "archive.php" actually gets triggered.

I think i didn't deploy it correctly. I am still not entirely sure what template hierarchies are called though.